# How to get union of 3 tables in sqlite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have 3 tables table a,b and c. I want `( select * from a  intersect select * from b intersect select * from c )  union  ( select * from a intersect select * from b )`
this gives error "("Syntax error
Without "( )" it works fine but it can't give the right result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SELECT in parentheses is a subquery, but [compound queries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) must be constructed of 'normal' queries.

Using parentheses to group compound operators is correct, but then you have to add a separate SELECT at the top level:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM a
               INTERSECT
               SELECT * FROM b
               INTERSECT
               SELECT * FROM c)
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM a
               INTERSECT
               SELECT * FROM b)
```

(Note: this construction does not actually make sense; (A ⋂ B ⋂ C) ⋃ (A ⋂ B) is the same as A ⋂ B.)

Answer (score -1):

```
(select * from a) 
   union
((select * from b) minus (select * from a))  
   union
((select * from c) minus ((select * from a) union (select * from b)))
```

First part is table a.
Second part is table b except overlapped with table a.
Third part is table c except overlapped with table a or table b.
Union of these three parts is union of three tables.

Ven diagram of three tabels (circles) may help to understand.

Comment: This is not valid SQL.